# Red dot displayed, review queue is empty

Tags: bug, review

The review queue is empty, but a red dot is displayed:

[image]

I have not skipped any questions in last couple of weeks. So skipped questions cannot be a reason.

I have not reached the limit of 20 answers per day. So this is also not the reason.

There are many similar questions to mine. Here are just a few examples:

- https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10381/what-does-the-red-circle-mean-next-to-a-review-queue
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358151/is-there-an-issue-with-the-review-queue-indicator-today

Some of the answers [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358152) say that it was resolved. But the problem still persists. And this is not a one time problem. Today, over 6 hours and multiple logins, the red dot is permanently displayed even if the queue "Close Votes" is empty.

If the red dot is useless, why displaying it at all?

Comment: Some of the existing meta posts (including one you linked to) explain this - eg "This was triggered by the queue having a pile of tag wiki excerpt edits, @DarkCygnus (yours, in fact). That's gonna be tricky to fix - they're only accessible to 5K+ users, but the queue doesn't know this until you try to edit (not that it matters for you, since you can't review your own edits - but it stops a lot of normal reviewers from clearing them)"

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Could you please explain how the tag wiki edits can affect the "Close Votes" queue?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking - that quote was just one example (from Shog) of how the red dot may not be indicative of the truth.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: In my opinion this example is not relevant to my case. That's why I am asking you why do you think it is relevant. If it is not relevant, why are you referring it? :)

Comment: It's just another queue. The reasons shog gave in that answer are relevant for your issue as well.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: No, the reasons of shog refer to the Sugested Edits queue. They include also tags, which requires particular rating. The Close Votes queue has nothing to do with tags and thus has no hidden components that require higher rating. Thus the comment of shog is *not relevant* to my case. If it is relevant, please explain how. I am asking for the 3rd time to explain why you think it is relevant.

Comment: It doesn't matter which queue it is - they all have issues like this. That was simply the first example. meta.se is the best place to look, as this subject has been answered many times.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: What should we do so that SE fixes it?

Comment: SE staff do see all bug posts on each meta site, so there is not much else we can do at this end.

Comment: I've notice this bug on SE for years.  It applies to all the SE sites.  I wrote a meta about it years ago somewhere on SE, but nothing ever got fixed.  Maybe it hasn't been a priority to fix for all those years... I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the page, I see 38 reviews pending in the Close Vote review queue. (You might be able to see this by yourself by opening a private/incognito window and navigate to https://security.stackexchange.com/review. )

[image]

But if you've skipped those 38 review items, the queue will appear empty to you.

The red dot is not cached on user level, that would be too expensive.

Comment: I have updated the question. I didn't see any questions in the queue and I still don't see any. But the red dot is still displayed.

Comment: In that screenshot, you're still logged in. What happens if you open that link in a window/browser where you're not logged in?

Comment: Now it is not displayed. When it displayed again, I will check it.